# Service Worker - Ignore parameter when caching

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I want `/search?q=query111` and `/search?q=query222`, `/search?q=query333` to use the same name: "search".
I can't find any way to do it works.

```
registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => {
    var url = new URL(request.url)
    return url.pathname === "/search"
  },
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: "search",
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxAgeSeconds: 48 * 60 * 60,
        maxEntries: 300,
        purgeOnQuotaError: true
      }),
    ]
  })
)
```

[image]